# Is there a free, large database of land sales in the US?

Tags: machine-learning, data.gov, real-estate, prices, land

I'm looking for a database which contains:

1. The location and ideally other basic information (acres).
2. The sale price (and date sold)

I am looking for something which is geared towards sales of mostly non-developed land including small sales, though if you have a real estate database that is similar, I would appreciate that too.

I am looking for at least a couple thousand sales, but ideally much more.

I have seen the other questions on this site which are real estate oriented, but aren't what I'm looking for.